# (Angular app) Copy current page url to mongodb

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, angular-ui-router, fetch-api

In my Angular project I am figuring out a method to directly copy current page url and send it into mongodb

Url is this. any suggestion will be appreciated

http://localhost:4201/contact?pincode=4343&devicetype=desktop&country=india

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the URL from `Router`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd  } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  currentPageURL: string = '';

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.currentPageURL= res.url;
    });
  }
}
```

Now you have your current URL value in `currentPageURL` variable. You can use this to pass the value to your API to be saved in MongoDB.

Comment: Hi CodeWarrior, Thankyou for the help.  router.events.filter is giving error (Cannot find name 'router'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.router'?)

Comment: hey thanks for updating. but it is giving new error   Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'

Comment: updated the answer, filter needed to be pipe which I have now. Also, check the console.log for the res and grab what you need from there