# (Angular app) Send data to API so that it can be called in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, rest

For a project I am figuring a way out to send fetched data to API from where it can be inserted into MongoDB. Really grateful for your suggestions.

data is successfully visible in console.log

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParam => {
      this.pincodeid = queryParam.pincode;
      this.devicetype = queryParam.devicetype;
      this.country = queryParam.country;
      console.log(queryParam);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sam, did my answer to your other question help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740440/2636938

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.